Causal mediation analysis via g-computation - why randomly permute the simulated mediator?
I have been reading about causal mediation analysis in settings where there is time-varying confounding of the mediator-outcome relationship. The estimands in question are the randomized analogues of the natural direct/indirect effects where Ma (the counterfactual values of the mediator under treatment a) is replaced with Ga|C, where Ga|C is a random draw from the distribution of the mediator under treatment a conditional on covariates. To my knowledge this type of estimands were originally proposed in this paper: https://journals.lww.com/epidem/fulltext/2014/03000/effect_decomposition_in_the_presence_of_an.22.aspx
Specifically, I've been looking at the following papers detailing:

a marginal structural model approach: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5560424/
a parametric g-formula approach: https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/27984420/
software implementation: https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/34028370/ - detail of estimation at https://bs1125.github.io/CMAverse/articles/overview.html#confounders-affected-by-the-exposure-1

My question is about a step in the g-formula approach that I don't understand - specifically step 2b in the g-formula paper (p270) or step 5 in the g-formula approach on the cmaverse page, where the simulated values of the mediator are randomly permuted. If I understand correctly, this means that the N simulated values of the mediator are randomly reassigned to different sample members. The same step is absent from the MSM approach, which simply uses the simulated values of the mediator.
The thing I don't understand is why it is necessary to randomly permute the simulated values, which are already a random draw from the modelled distribution of the mediator conditional on covariates. Does this not also break the 'conditional on covariates' bit of the original definition?

In mediation analysis, there are various families of parameters that quantify different notions of effect mediation. Each family has its own motivations, properties, strengths, and weaknesses. For example, Judea Pearl's natural direct and indirect effects$^{[1]}$ can be formulated as follows:
\begin{aligned}
 \operatorname{NDE}_{10} &= \mathbb{E}\left[Y_{1,M_0}\right]-\mathbb{E}\left[Y_{0,M_0} \right],\\
\operatorname{NIE}_{10} &= \mathbb{E}\left[Y_{1,M_1}\right]-\mathbb{E}\left[Y_{1,M_0} \right].
\end{aligned}
Notice that $\operatorname{NDE}_{10}+\operatorname{NIE}_{10}=\mathbb{E}\left[Y_{1,M_1}\right]-\mathbb{E}\left[Y_{0,M_0}\right]=\operatorname{ATE}$$^{[2]}$. In fact, this decomposition is one of the most desired properties of the natural family, as it allows for the analysis of mediation in compositional terms: what fraction the effect occurs outside the mediation mechanism (direct) versus how much occurs through it (indirect). However, a notable weakness of this approach is that the conditions for identification are hard, and a little controversial. For instance, having access to a set of covariates $X$, sufficient conditions for identifying the natural effects are:

$X$ contains all confounders $A-Y$; so $Y_{a,m}\perp A\mid X,\ \forall a\in\{0,1\},m\in\mathcal{M}$
$X$ contains all confounders $A-M$: so $M_{a}\perp A\mid X,\ \forall a\in\{0,1\}$
$X$ contains all confounders $M-Y$: $Y_{a,m}\perp M\mid X,A=a, \forall a\in\{0,1\},m\in\mathcal{M}$
$X$ cannot have descendants of $A$ and the cross-world independence assumption must hold: $Y_{a',m}\perp M_{a}\mid X,\ \forall a,a'\in\{0,1\},m\in\mathcal{M}$.

Assumptions 1. and 2. can be ensured through the randomization of $A$, while assumption 3. can be supported by background knowledge. However, assumption 4. is particularly contentious because it is a counterfactual assertion that cannot be empirically tested. This is due to the fact that it involves random variables that exist in entirely separate and opposing world scenarios.
Thus, an alternative to the natural family is VanderWeele's randomized interventional family. This family of parameters is discussed in your referenced materials, where the randomized direct and indirect effects$^{[3]}$ can be expressed as follows:
\begin{aligned}
 \operatorname{RDE}_{10} &= \mathbb{E}\left[Y_{1,G_0}\right]-\mathbb{E}\left[Y_{0,G_0} \right],\\
\operatorname{RIE}_{10} &= \mathbb{E}\left[Y_{1,G_1}\right]-\mathbb{E}\left[Y_{1,G_0} \right],
\end{aligned}
where $G_a$ represents a random draw from the distribution of $M_a$. Notice that, because $G_a$ is effectively randomized, it is, by design, independent of $Y_{a',m}$, while still maintaining the same marginal distribution as $M_a$. This randomization breaks the problematic dependence by swapping the background units, thereby eliminating the need for assumption 4.
Additionally, this approach allows for adjustment for confounders $L_a$ of the $M-Y$ relationship that are influenced by the exposure. However, this family sacrifices the ability to decompose the total effect, as $\operatorname{RDE}_{10} + \operatorname{RIE}_{10} \neq \operatorname{ATE}$.
How is sampling from $G_a\sim M_a$ performed?

The distribution of $M_a$ can be approximated using in-sample predictions or generations of $M_a$ from a (semi-parametric) regression or probabilistic model.
Sampling from this distribution can be done with replacement or without replacement. The latter is equivalent to a permutation of units, as the approximated distribution has finite support (finite number of units).
Sampling can also be done conditionally, or for each stratum, where $G_a \mid X$ is drawn from the distribution of $M_a \mid X$. I believe this is the original proposal by VanderWeele, but may be more challenging when $X$ includes continuous or high-dimensional covariates, and when the sample size is small.

TL;DR: permutation is equivalent in this context to a sampling procedure without replacement. Sampling mimics a randomization design for the mediator, making the randomized mediation effects easier to identify than the natural mediation effects, particularly under exposure-induced confounders $L_a$ of $M-Y$.

$^{[1]}$ Pearl, J. (2001). Direct and indirect effects. In Proceedings of the Seventeenth Conference on Uncertainty in Artificial Intelligence, pages 411–420. Morgan Kaufmann Publishers Inc. 2, 3, 7, 8, 16
$^{[2]}$ In fact Pearl originally defines the $\operatorname{NIE}$ as $\operatorname{NIE}^*_{10}=\mathbb{E}\left[Y_{0,M_1}\right]-\mathbb{E}\left[Y_{0,M_0} \right]$, which is a different parameter than $\operatorname{NIE}_{10}$, and its reverse $\operatorname{NIE}^*_{01}$ leads to a related but different decomposition of the $\operatorname{ATE}$.
$^{[3]}$ VanderWeele, T. J., Vansteelandt, S., and Robins, J. M. (2014). Effect decomposition in the presence of an exposure-induced mediator-outcome confounder. Epidemiology (Cambridge, Mass.), 25(2):300. 4, 9, 10

Thanks Johan - that's very helpful - I gather that you/cmaverse are using the unconditional Ga, which differs from the original Ga|C. Given that the conditional effects using Ga|C are averaged over C anyway in the original, how does that affect the interpretation/estimation of the effects (assuming that it's not the same)?

You're right, it does change the interpretation. The RDE/RIE with conditional sampling given $X$ will be "closer" to the NDE/NIE, as more information from the same unit is used in the simulated randomization for its assigned mediator value. However, conditional sampling can be more challenging to implement for high-dimensional or continuous $X$. For instance, approximating sampling with a permutation may no longer be feasible or advisable.
